# Meteor MongoDB Getting an array from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to get one simple thing done by MongoDB 
without any luck for a week or so.

Here is a document I have
{
_id: "mkikuQzrYdyQjL7Ry",
links:[
 1: "link1"
 2: "link2"
 3: "link3"
 4: "link4"
 ]
}

How can I receive all the items from the "links" array with one request to MongoDB?

Comment: `console.log(YourCollectionName.findOne("mkikuQzrYdyQjL7Ry").links)`

Comment: Thank you, it works, such a simple thing that I couldn't find anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is
CollectionName.findOne("mkikuQzrYdyQjL7Ry").links
thanks to JeremyK && webdev